# Как определить конец списка в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть такой код:

```
for i in range(0,len(list)):
        if list[i] > list[i + 1]:
            pass
```

Как только `list[i]` становится последним элементом списка, `list[i + 1]` выдает ошибку (я по незнанию ожидал `None`). Как в Python определить конец списка?

Comment: `if i == len(list) - 1` очевидно

Comment: @andreymal не совсем понимаю как это должно работать

Comment: Длина списка к примеру 10, элементы нумеруются с нуля, первый элемент это 0, второй это 1, соответственно последний десятый это len(list)-1 → 10-1 → 9

Comment: Доступ к последнему элементу списка возможен как `some_list[-1]`

Answer (score 5):

Очень просто. Делать цикл не до последнего элемента, а до предпоследнего:

```
for i in range(len(list)-1):
```

PS. Не нужно называть список словом `list`. Это встроенная функция.

Comment: В данном случае мне нужен последний элемент — те отбрасывать нужно на уровне условия if.

Comment: Не понял. ``list[i+1]`` в вашем коде даст вам последний элемент.

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы пишете цикл по индексам, Вы еще не освоили python :)

```
a = (2,4,2,5,7)
for m, n in zip(a[:-1], a[1:]):
    print (m, n)
```

P.S. Если по результатом надо сформировать новый список, то вместо цикла for часто используют *генераторы списков*.

Answer (score 0):

```
t = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

for pos, i in enumerate(range(0,len(t)) ):
    if pos == len(t) - 1:
       print('Последний элемент', i)
    else:
        pass

# Вывод
# Последний элемент 8
```